# Debug asp.net4 website local session as the app pool identity

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

I have a bug in a website that is using trusted connect to access a database. I do not get the error when debugging locally. I believe this is down to the specific permissions assigned to my personal windows account.

Is there an easy way to run the website (visual studio 10 debugger/Casini) as the app pool identity in question and step through?

Answer (score 0):

You can actualy debug IIS process using Visual Studio.
Go to menu "Tools" and select "Attach to process..."

[image]

Make sure you check "Show processes from all users". You should be looking for "w3wp.exe".

In this way you can attach and debug process runing on IIS (your app).